# How to avoid data redundancy when copying between different DBMS?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm planning to create an VB.net application for retrieving data from a database (MS Access) and store it to a web server (MySQL data base). I really have confusion in my mind. I'm planning to use task scheduler so that the program will automatically run. I'm planning to set the time every 5 minutes.

How can I avoid the redundancy of data?

For example, I'm planning to get the sales for 5 minutes, after 5 minutes I will do it again. I think there will be redundancy in that case. I would like to ask your ideas about this scenario: how would you handle it?

Comment: so sir, in this case, it only depends on the program? to avoid redundacy?

Comment: Input sales data directly to MySQL, rather than going through an Access db file.  If you have an Access form-based application for data entry, replace the native (Jet/ACE) tables with ODBC links to their MySQL counterparts.  No more problems about keeping 2 separate sets of data synchronized.

Comment: @HansUp : sir, i dont have any idea about how to replace the native tables with ODBC.. My concept to do is that I will create a program that can fetch data from the Ms Access and then put it to the database of the web server(MySQL) so that it will be accessible through internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you said "*i dont have any idea about how to replace the native tables with ODBC*".

Is that the only obstacle which prevents you consolidating the data into one set in MySQL?  If so, try this suggestion for setting ODBC links to MySQL tables.

Install an ODBC driver for MySQL, if you don't have one already. The latest version is available here: [Download Connector/ODBC](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

Create a DSN (Data Source Name) for your MySQL database from the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator.

Create a new Access database and use the DSN to create links with guidance from the web page link @jmoreno provided.

If the Access names of the linked tables are different than the names you originally used for the native Access tables, change them to match those original names.

Then you can import your forms, queries, reports, etc. from the old Access application.  *Ideally* everything will just work, since Access will find the table names it needs and won't care that they are external instead of native tables.  However you many need to resolve any data type incompatibilities between Access and MySQL.

You would need the MySQL ODBC driver on each machine where the Access application is used.  Personally I would prefer to deal with that rather than the challenges of synchronizing between separate Access and MySQL data stores.  (YMMV)

When you're ready to deploy, you can convert the ODBC links to DSN-less connections so the client machines wouldn't need to each have the DSN configured.  See [Using DSN-Less Connections](http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html) by Doug Steele, Access MVP, for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If at all possible you should avoid using two databases in a situation like this.

Look for information on the linked table manager -- the data that Access uses doesn't have to be stored in Access.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1480/configure-microsoft-access-linked-tables-with-a-sql-server-database/

If you have to do this, then see about using/upgrading to Access 2010 and use data macros (triggers), to put the new/changed data into temp tables that you clear out once you've copied the data over.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to think very carefully about how you identify the data which has changed since the last synchronization cycle.  If every row of data has a 'last updated' timestamp (that is indexed) then you could write a process that selected the recently updated rows from each table in turn.  That's apt to be a bit heavy on the originating database (MS Access), plus you still have to identify the corresponding row to replace (where replacement is required) in the MySQL database.  Of course, you can put different tables on different change schedules.  For example, the table of US states probably doesn't change once a year, but your customer orders tables (or SO questions and answers tables) may change a lot in five minutes.

Some DBMS have alternative mechanisms, especially for working between copies of themselves.  Some DBMS also provide a mechanism that is sometimes called 'changed data capture' (CDC) that allows you to get the changed data.  Sometimes, in DBMS where you have a 'transaction log' or 'logical log' (but not CDC or something similar), you can 'mine' the log files (or log backups) to find the changes.  However, the logs are typically optimized for the DBMS internal recovery processes, not for your use.

Comment: Sir. Is there something to do with my query? can you elaborate more on CDC? @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you will have to keep track of data items (may be in a different metadata space/datastore) that you have already processed to avoid the redundancy. The metadata should be used to filter out records that have been processed from the source. The logic and what needs to be in the metadata would depend on the exact use case here.